# Perl Mechanize timeout not working with https

Tags: perl, https, timeout, mechanize

I've been using Perl's Mechanize library but for some reason with https the timeout parameter (I'm using Crypt::SSLeay for SSL).

> my $browser = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck=>0, timeout=>3);

Has anyone encountered this before and knows how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You kind of trailed off there in the first sentence.  What happens with the timeout parameter?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say the timeout parameter has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

*For HTPS/SSL you have to do some workaround:*

```
my $html = `wget -q -t 1 -T $timeout -O - $url`;
mech->get(0); 
$mech->update_html($html);
```

Answer (score 0):

In just testing it now against https://www.sourceforge.net/, I get the impression that the timeout argument *does* work, but that it doesn't work until after the HTTPS negotiation occurs.  I set the timeout really low, to a fractional value, and it reports a timeout correctly, but there is a delay much longer than my timeout value, and then it immediately returns with a timeout error.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
$|=1;

# This "works", downloading the page within the timeout period
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(
    timeout => 3,
);
$mech->get( 'https://www.sourceforge.net/' );
print "Successful get.\n";

# This throws a connect timeout, but after a delay much longer than 50ms
my $mech2 = WWW::Mechanize->new(
    timeout => 0.05,
);
$mech2->get( 'https://www.sourceforge.net/' );
print "Successful get 2.\n";
```

Output:

```
Successful get.
Error GETing http://sourceforge.net/: Can't connect to sourceforge.net:80
(connect: timeout) at ./throwaway22855.pl line 20
```

---

It appears the timeout is handled deep down below in IO::Socket, using `select`.  On some systems, this may interfere with `SIGALRM`, so if you want to work around this and write your own timeout, make sure you read your platform's implementation docs.  Also note (in `perldoc perlipc`) that Perl has used deferred signals since 5.8.x, so setting an alarm by hand may not work without using the `sigprocmask` workaround.

There is some more information here:
[SIGALRM Timeout -- How does it affect existing operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241634/sigalrm-timeout-how-does-it-affect-existing-operations/3241672#3241672)